# Не бывает изменений на сайте scss

Tags: html, css, css3, scss, sass

После того,как сделал изменения в scss файле - изменения не бывает.На картинке в консоли разработчика нужный scss файл.Я нашёл этот scss файл в проекте,внёс свои изменения,но они не отображаются на сайте.Я хотел добавить вертикальный скролл,я уже через консоль разраба проверял,всё ок было.И мои изменения есть в этом scss файле,через консоль разраба тоже проверял.Кеш браузера,проекта и т.п тоже очищал[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну а собрать-то из scss в css не забыли?